# Best practices for multiple clients in apache Apache Airflow/Cloud Composer?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Problem:

- several tasks/jobs that need to be executed for a client
- a lot of clients (hundreds)
- tasks/jobs are nearly identical, only config changes

Are there any best practices in Airflow to keep things simple? I'm thinking about (in no specific order):

- **specific client configs** as possible (override defaults when needed)
- **ui overview**: job per client would make it very difficult to get an overview
- **modularity**: re-use of code as much as possible
- **performance**: clients should not hinder one another (too much)
- **scaling**: it should be easy to increase performance (preferably horizontally)
- **fault-tolerance**: when things fail for one client they don't hinder others + clear ui indication
- **re-execution**: easy to manually re-execute for 1 client
- **setup**: setting up a new client should be easy (and using code/config, no ui)
- **governance**: easy to evaluate code changes and enforce rules
- **clean-up**: easy to remove a client
- etc.

I cannot find a lot of material on this particular use case.

Ideally we have one "template" that is re-used per client. It is unclear whether one job or multiple jobs are the best solution. Or maybe there is another way that better suits this usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Airflow has extensive support for the Google Cloud Platform. But note that most Hooks and Operators are in the contrib section, which means that they have a beta status, meaning that they can have breaking changes between minor releases.

**Number of client aspects:**

There can be as many DAGs as is needed and each one of them can mention multiple tasks. It is recommended to keep one logical workflow in one DAG file and try keep it very light (e.g. configuration file). It allows taking less time and resources for the Airflow scheduler to process them at each heartbeat.

It is possible to create DAGs (with the same base code) dynamically based on any number of configuration parameters, which is really helpful and time-saving option when having a lot of clients.

To create new DAGs, please create a DAG template within the `create_dag` function. Code can be wrapped in a method that allows for custom parameters to be passed in. Moreover, the input parameters don't have to exist in the dag file itself. Another common form of generating DAGs is by setting values in a `Variable` object. Plese, refer [here](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/) for further information.

**Specific client configs:**

You can use Macros are used to pass dynamic information into task instances at runtime. A list of default variables accessible in all templates can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros.html).

Airflow’s built-in support for [Jinja templating](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/tutorial.html#templating-with-jinja) enables users to pass arguments that can be used in templated fields.

**UI overview**

If your dag takes long time to load, you could reduce the value of `default_dag_run_display_number` configuration in airflow.cfg to a smaller value. This configurable controls the number of dag run to show in UI with default value 25.

**Modularity**

If a dictionary of `default_args` is passed to a DAG, it will apply them to any of its operators. This makes it easy to apply a common parameter to many operators without having to type it many times.

Take a look for example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('my_dag', default_args=default_args)
op = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy', dag=dag)
print(op.owner) # Airflow
```

For more information about the BaseOperator’s parameters and what they do, refer to the [airflow.models.BaseOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/index.html#airflow.models.BaseOperator) documentation.

**Performance**

It is possible to use variables, which you could control to improve airflow DAG performance (possible to set in the airflow.cfg.):

- `parallelism`: controls the number of task instances that runs simultaneously across the whole Airflow cluster.
- `concurrency`: The Airflow scheduler will run no more than concurrency task instances for your DAG at any given time. Concurrency is defined in your Airflow DAG. If you do not set the concurrency on your DAG, the scheduler will use the default value from the dag_concurrency entry in your airflow.cfg.
- `task_concurrency`: This variable controls the number of concurrent running task instances across dag_runs per task.
- `max_active_runs`: the Airflow scheduler will run no more than max_active_runs DagRuns of your DAG at a given time.
- `pool`: This variable controls the number of concurrent running task instances assigned to the pool.

You can see the airflow config in the composer instance bucket `gs://composer_instance_bucket/airflow.cfg`. You can tune this configuration as you wish, but keep in mind that cloud composer has some configurations blocked.

**Scaling**

Please, keep in mind that is recommended that the number of nodes must be greater than 3, keeping this number below to 3 could cause some issues, if you want to up upgrade the number of nodes you can use the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/update#--node-count) to specify this value. Also please note that, there are some airflow configurations related to autoscalling blocked and can't be [overridden](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/airflow-configurations).
Some Airflow configurations are preconfigured for Cloud Composer, and you cannot change them.

**Fault-tolerance**

Please, refer to following [documentation](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/executors/mesos_executor/index.html?highlight=fault%20tolerant).

**Re-execution**

Just like object is an instance of a class, an Airflow task is an instance of an [Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#operators) ([BaseOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py)). So write a "re-usable" operator and use it hundreds of times across your pipelines simply by passing different params.

**Latency**

It is possible to reduce airflow DAG scheduling latency in production by using:

- `max_threads`: Scheduler will spawn multiple threads in parallel to schedule dags. This is controlled by max_threads with default value of 2.
- `scheduler_heartbeat_sec`: User should consider to increase scheduler_heartbeat_sec config to a higher value(e.g 60 secs) which controls how frequent the airflow scheduler gets the heartbeat and updates the job’s entry in database.

Please refer to following articles about best practices:

- [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/best-practices.html)
- [Medium](https://medium.com/datareply/airflow-lesser-known-tips-tricks-and-best-practises-cf4d4a90f8f)

I hope it will helps you in some way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive overview!! Do you have any recommendation on the client aspect, ie creating 1 dag for all clients or 1 dag per client? I’ve seen dynamic dag construction that creates multiple dags from 1 template.

Comment: There can be as many DAGs as you need. Although each one can mention multiple tasks, it’s a good idea to keep one logical workflow in one file. It is critical to keep DAG files very light (like a configuration file) so that it takes less time and resources for the Airflow scheduler to process them at each heartbeat. So you can specify default DAG args. I would suggest to use 1DAG per client and use dynamic creation of DAG, as you said. And you can use parallelism option. Hope you will manage it. Also, take a look https://gtoonstra.github.io/etl-with-airflow/

Comment: Please also, consider accepting the answer if you think it was useful, thanks!

Comment: you suggest using the multiple dags approach (I imagine it working like this: https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/) could you maybe update your answer with this information? For future reference, I think it is important that the answer contains relevant information for choosing a per-client dag vs a per-client task. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonny5 I updated my answer with dynamically generating DAGs considering number of clients aspect, thanks!